# Django/CKeditor Erro build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' Request

Tags: django, ckeditor

[image: Imagem do erro]

> build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' Request
>   Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8888/admin/videos/videos/1/change/ Django
>   Version:  1.11 Exception Type:    TypeError Exception Value:
>   build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' Exception
>   Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py
>   in render, line 111 Python
>   Executable:   /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6 Python Version:    3.6.0
>   Python Path:   ['/Users/carlos/Workspace/py/www/rock', 
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Estou utilizando Python 3.6, Django 1.11, Pillow 4.0

Quando desabilito o CKeditor tudo funciona, então existe alguma incompatibilidade envolvendo o CKeditor com o Django 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver fazendo downgrade do Django de 1.11 para 1.10.6

Fiz upgrade cedo demais para a ultima versão do Django.

Answer (score 1):

file widgets.py (cked), fix code

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if value is None:
        value = ''

    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs, name=name)

    self.options['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = reverse('cked_elfinder')

    return mark_safe(render_to_string('cked/ckeditor.html', {
        'final_attrs': flatatt(final_attrs),
        'value': conditional_escape(force_unicode(value)),
        'id': final_attrs['id'],
        'options': json_encode(self.options)})
    )

def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Helper function for building an attribute dictionary.
    This is combination of the same method from Django<=1.10 and Django1.11+
    """
    attrs = dict(base_attrs, **kwargs)
    if extra_attrs:
        attrs.update(extra_attrs)
    return attrs
```

Issue 364 https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/pull/364/files

Comment: O código é a solução? poderia evidenciar isso?

Comment: Esta solução me parece um fix do próprio app do ckeditor, certo? Eles vão lançar uma nova versão com a fix?